# CORS security exception in Safari 5.1 only

Tags: javascript, safari, cors

I'am trying to make CORS working in Safari. I ended up testing base canvas functionality with a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kamuniaft/dbf50wzz/ 
The code is very simple

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas_id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    console.log(myCanvas.toDataURL());
};
img.src = 'http://sibngp.ru/assets/img/slides/thumbs/1.jpg';
```

It works ok with chrome and ff but fails with security exception in Safari (Actually i have only Safari 5.1 for Windows). I know, that Safari supports CORS from version 4 so it should work and i definitely done something wrong. The only thing that can go wrong here is headers, but they actually seems ok, and i experimented with them a lot. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: safari is no longer supported on windows and hasn't been for a few years

Comment: @Pete, well, i know that. It's an old Safari 5.1 as i said. But nevertheless CORS should work there, i think.